# Cross compiling Openssl with the x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc compiler on a Fedora 29 host

Tags: gcc, openssl, fedora-29

I am trying to cross compile openssl using the x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc on a Fedora 29 host.

I am getting this error:

```
cryptlib.h:62:11: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
```

The compile command is:

```
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -o cryptlib.o cryptlib.c
```

As I understand it, the compiler should find stdlib.h in it's standard path since it has been included with <..>.

I tried testing for it using the pre processor, which said that it can't find it.

```
echo '#include <stdlib.h>' | x86_64-linux-gnu-cpp -H -o /dev/null
```

:1:10: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory

I tested for another header file, it it was able to find it.

```
echo '#include <stdbool.h>' | x86_64-linux-gnu-cpp -H -o /dev/null
```

. /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/include/stdbool.h

Has anyone come across this issue ?.

Regards
Chandana

Comment: How did you install the `x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc` cross compiler?